# In TYPO3 6.x BE, how to enable another doktype's fields in a sysfolder

Tags: typo3, backend

In TYPO3 6.x, I have a sysfolder where I would like to enable the "abstract" and "media" fields in the  Backend page settings. How can this be done?

PS The reason for is that I need their contents cascading to subpages. But the sysfolder/page they're on can't be displayed in the FE, so I want to prevent editors from adding content.

Comment: I've found a workaround already for the problem: create an empty Backend Layout, apply it to that page, re-assign the regular layout to subpages. But still, it would be interesting to know how to modify page settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest workaround without manipulating the TypoScript (so it can be clicked-out in 5 seconds) is creating a `Shortcut` instead of `SysFolder`, it will behave similar, but you'll keep the page typical fields. Theoretically `SysFolders` shouldn't be used for storing subpages therefore `Shortcuts` are *more appropriate*

- Create a `Shortcut` page type and set its mode to  `First subpage of selected/current page`
- Hide this page in menus
- If using RealURL check the `Exclude from speaking URL` checkbox.
- Create subpages of that.

That's all

Comment: Great, but in the page module for shortcut, editors still *are* able to create tt_content items. My workaround with an empty BE layout doesn't work 100% as well (not in "languages" view")

Comment: Using `List` module they are even able to create `tt_content` in SysFolders. You can use `Access` module to restrict this possibility on pages where contents shouldn't be inserted, so non-admins won't be able to edit contente elements there